# MAUI debugging: cannot step into dependency project

Tags: android, xamarin, .net-core, maui

I'm developing a mobile app using MAUI on Visual Studio 2022. I have a main project which includes most functionality for both android and ios. Additionally I have created a second project targeting net6.0-android, which implements some android-specific functionality. It is used by the main project.

Problem: When I set breakpoints in the second project, the debugger breaks on the calling line in the main project. I cannot step in the second project. What could cause this problem and how to solve it?

EDIT:
Repro steps:

1. Create a new maui project A
2. Create another project B in the same solution and target net6.0-android
3. Reference project B in project A
4. Use some function from B in project A and set breakpoint inside that function in B
5. Execution will break on the calling line in project A, not on the actualbreakpoint in project B

Comment: Could you provide some code related or error message?

Comment: There is no related code or error message. Added repro steps in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by when the dependency project has [DeterministicSourcePaths](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/blob/main/docs/README.md#deterministicsourcepaths) set to true.

> Only set DeterministicSourcePaths to true on a build/CI server, never for local builds.

If this is set to true then the first part of the path in the call stack will look like `/_/MyProject...`

Try disabling this on your second (i.e. Project B) project and rebuilding, the paths in the PDB will then match to the files on your operating system and Visual Studio will be able to find them.

Answer (score -1):

Following your steps I tested the code, and the problem happened just as you said.
I searched relevant information about it. Unfortunately, that is not recommended to do with it by adding a new project to the solution.

You can use [`Invoke platform code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code) that MAUI provided. Also you can refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829758/how-to-create-an-android-foreground-service-in-maui/73849475#73849475).

Comment: Where did you find the information that this is not the recommended way to do this? I'm developing a utility library, and can't put all the code into a single monolithic library.